# How to integrate code-generators with catkin

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to integrate some code-generators into catkin.
In contrast to the ROS message generator, they produce .h and .cpp files.
So where are those files supposed to go?
The ROS message generator writes the generated .h files into devel/include/xyz/.
But where would the .cpp files go in this case?
Most code generators are not too happy about writing .h and .cpp to different locations.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189071/how-to-integrate-code-generators-with-catkin/) by [roadrunner](https://answers.ros.org/users/9576/roadrunner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-08-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In catkin, the "right" thing to do is probably to put the generated cpp files in build/ somewhere, and the generated headers in devel/include/package/

If your code generator isn't happy generating into multiple directories, you could probably generate into build/ and then have a second cmake target which copies the headers into devel/include/

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roadrunner](https://answers.ros.org/users/9576/roadrunner/) on 2014-08-06**:
Thanks for the pointers. I'll try that.